# Why won't a method execute from within LINQ Where method

Tags: c#, linq

In a console app, from a static method in main class Program, I am calling:

```
internal class Module
{
    public bool EnsureModuleLocalInstall()
    {
        if (CheckModuleUpToDateLocal())
            return true;
        else if (DownloadComponentData())
            if(InstallModuleLocal())
                return true;

        return false;
    }
}

var availableModules = new List<Module>();
... // Add several 'Modules' to list
var installed = availableModules.Where(m => m.EnsureModuleLocalInstall());
```

I have both set a break-point, and also checked the expected outcome (module installed locally), but from all indications the method 'EnsureModuleLocalInstall' is not being executed.

Am I missing something obvious, or am I expecting too much from the LINQ 'Where' method and should use a LINQ ForEach?

Comment: Do you understand [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)?

Comment: As a general rule, LINQ is not suitable for defining and running queries with side effects.. Not surprised that you had the expectation of the method getting called, as you **defined** the query.

Comment: Yes, and thank you. Embarrassing- all I needed to do was add a ToList().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Where` method is implemented using [deferred execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738633(v=vs.100).aspx), so the query won't actually be run until you iterate over the result. The simplest way to get your list of installed modules is to call `ToList` on the query return value:

```
var installed = availableModules.Where(m => m.EnsureModuleLocalInstall()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, yes as Jesse Good pointed out- it was deferred, and never executed.

Answer (score 3):

Most LINQ methods (like the `Where` method) will return to you an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` that does not contain the result of the query but instead contains all the information necessary to execute the query. The query is only executed when you start enumerating the `IEnumerable<T>`. This is called Deferred Execution.

One way to enumerate the `IEnumerable<T>` is to invoke `ToList` like this:

```
var installed = availableModules.Where(m => m.EnsureModuleLocalInstall()).ToList();
```

Comment: Deferred execution is a synonym of **Lazy evaluation** or laziness. In a computational  context, it is also called Symbolic calculations